# How to center an image created in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, cross-browser

I have this very simple code, the problem is it doesn't give the same output using Firefox and IE: in Firefox, the images are superposed but right-aligned, and in IE they are superposed and left aligned.
What I want is that the images will be centered and superposed.
I have to create images using Javascript to use a special library in creating the images.

Thank you for your help.

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="Container">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write('<img id="image1" src="image1.jpg">')
            document.write('<img id="image1" src="image2.jpg">')
        </script>   
    </div>    
</body>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e8e6e7;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#Container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#image1 {
    position : absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#image2 {
    position : absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Y'all all need to learn how to use comments properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change second image id to `image2`.
2 tricks for centering your images is:

add one of these classes to your images:

```
.center {
  display: block; /*can remove this line*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.center {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -[your image width / 2]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are making `#image1` and `#image2` be absolutely positionined, they will not adjust the width/height of the `#Container`. This means you can't center it, because it doesn't have the proportions to center.

The code below makes **only one image be absolutely positioned**. This lets your other image act as expected. You can do whatever you want with the "overlay" image.

I also included `z-index`, which can let you change the order of the images. This isn't necessary for this example, but if you add more images, it may be useful.

### HTML

```
<div id="Container">
    <div class="image-wrap">
        <img id="image1" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/fa00fa/fff.png"/>
        <img id="image2" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/00ff33/000000.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#Container .image-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#image1 {
    position : relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
#image2 {
    position : absolute; /* Different than #image1 */
    z-index: 20; /* On top of #image2 */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* Assuming width/height of both images are the same */
}
```

### JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n496j/1/

Answer (score 0):

well, it will help if the images would sit in some container with `text-align:center;`.

**something like this:**

```
// body can be be replaced with any element which contains the images
body{ text-align:center; }
body > img{ display:inline-block; max-width:49%; }
```

**Demo page:
http://jsbin.com/hehot/1/edit**

Answer (score 0):

Use the css

```
img{  display:block; margin: auto; }
```